# qooxdoo qx.ui.mobile.list package not loading

Tags: qooxdoo

I have just started evaluating qooxdoo + phonegap for a mobile application and have completed the getting started manual and created a test application which works as expected. The default app created has page1 with a button to navigate to page2 and back.

I have edited application.js to show a list by copying the list sample script into it but the list creation fails with error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'List' of undefined`

I have tried looking into the documentation to see if i have to make any changes to the app to load the list package but have not able to find anything. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `./generate.py source` did not help `./generate.py source-all` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Did you call

```
./generate.py source
```

after adding the qx.Mobile list to your application?